# How to distribute a report from MS Access to Sharepoint Online

Tags: ms-access

In the Microsoft support document Distribute a report [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/distribute-a-report-561a9066-00ab-41ee-8f07-a0734810a778] is a section: Export a report to a folder or Sharepoint document library.

The description does not match with my MS Access version. 
My version is Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365.

Can anybode tell me how to enter the URL of Sharepoint Online in the navigation pane?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the instructions are that you want to put a word file, a pdf file, a text file or whatever into that SharePoint folder.

So, the advice in that example is NOT limited to Access. All they are saying is to run the report, export it as a PDF file. You are THEN free to copy and place that resulting PDF file into that shared folder on SharePoint. So, how you get/place/copy that PDF file into that folder is the same as how you would copy a word file, a excel file or any kind of windows file into that folder.

Quite sure you just type in the URL that points to the folder name, and then you are free to use the up-load files option in the SharePoint site. The other way is to use the "map" folder option from SharePoint, and that will give you a look alike or useable folder from the windows explore. So, how you get the exported Access PDF file (the report that is now a simple PDF) into that folder is no different then how you  copy any other file into that SharePoint folder.

If a user can't copy or get a word file, a text file, Excel file, or in this case a simple PDF file into that folder, then all is lost here.

You are being asked to place/copy a pane jane windows file.

So, you run the Access report. In the ribbon (assuming Access 2007 or later) there is a export to PDF option. You  thus create the PDF file on your computer, and then place that file on the Shared folder on SharePoint. So the REAL question here is?

I have a file on my computer - how can I place it into a SharePoint folder? How this works for ANY file, including that PDF you created (exported) from Access is 100% the same.

So, users will have to learn how to place a file into that SharePoint folder. Once they learn how to do this, then they can place any file - such as a PDF in this case into that folder.

So, creating that plain jane PDF file from the Access report results in a static PDF file, and then you simply copy that file to the SharePoint folder.

Now, you might want to be able to skip the step after you create the PDF, and it would be more convenient to simply specify the URL WHEN exporting the PDF from Access. As noted, to do this you need to map the SharePoint folder to a windows folder, and then this will work.

The steps are:
Log into https://portal.office.com
Click on your apps menu and choose SharePoint
Browse to a document library > Documents
In the bottom left corner of the browser click the “Return to classic SharePoint”

You have to set trusted locations. The full set of steps for this are here:

https://jasoncoltrin.com/2018/10/25/solved-sharepoint-office365-open-with-explorer-not-working-on-windows-10-internet-explorer-11/

Once that folder can be used/seen in windows, then you can specify that folder when you export the PDF. Only you can decide if all those extra steps are worth the effort, or that users just place the resulting PDF file into that SharePoint folder the SAME WAY that they now  place any old windows file into that SharePoint folder.

Comment: I expect the possibility to place the PDF report directly from Access in Sharepoint, not via the file system, Access can also export tables and queries to Sharepoint. And all the other Office products like Word and Excel can work directly with Sharepoint. Acrobat reader can add Sharepoint as a Storage account to store in Sharepoint. My question was when I generate a report in Access in pdf how to store it directly in Sharepoint, not via the filesystem and not by a upload action in Sharepoint.

Comment: You have to use the file system. Its simply the way it works.As noted, if you  map a your drive, then you  can specify the mapped drive that points to the folder, and thus you can do this in one operation. There is really not much or any better support for saving a pdf to  SharePoint. So, if the drive been mapped, then when viewing the report, you  can choose PDF, and specify the shared folder for the output. So that would save the  "outside" of access manual copy part.  You could try the URL like when  using word or excel and see if that works (it might), but if not then mapped folder is ok.

Comment: I just tested this. You don't even need a mapped drive. So, specify the url to the documents folder, or whatever, and the PDF will be saved in that folder. So, you don't even need a mapped drive. So, https://yourCompnay.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/TeamSite/MyPdf.pdf file will work. Just go into that folder where you  want to send hte pdf, and right click on any existing file, and copy link. the URL you get (with the file name removed) is what you can use in this case. This will allow you to skip the manual file copy part.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for. Now back to my question: how did you do that? Where do you paste the URL (with the filname removed)? 
FYI: When I right click on a existing file in SP their is no filename like MyPdf.pdf but a code like yourCompnay.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/TeamSite/EWDSCPrm6jhFgqRdBiWIfBMBhKEKMmQE7p18W0BbuYcVtA?e=W3GukA

Comment: well, there is the standard right click in a browswer that gives you a link, and every browser has worked that way for 20 years. However, depending on the document and view settings in Sharepoint that right click gets hi-jacked into some custom garbage that you don't want. All you have to do is simply enter in the site url/documents when you choose PDF from the Access report ribbion. So, just do this: https://mycompnay.sharepoint.com/sites/New365/Shared%20Documents/MyReport.pdf So in above, just type in the url of the sub site and documents site, and simply enter the name you want .

Comment: My question was about how to past a url in the filesystem dialog of Access. I can only past a location of the local filesystem (i.e. D:\Archive\) not a URL.